# Found Once in a Sword! 

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I can be weighed, but have no mass
>
> I can be found once in a sword
>
> I can be thoughtful or thoughtless
>
> And I can exit through a cord
>
> What am I?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is:

> Word.

**I can be weighed, but have no mass**

> A word has a weight associated to it depending upon the context.

**And I can be found once in a sword**

> Word is found once in sword

**I can be thoughtful or thoughtless**

> A word can be thoughtful or thoughtless.

**And I can exit through a cord**

> Electronic 'Word' can be exited through cord / wire.

**As per the title**, until and unless it was put on a paper /electronic format!

> word can be hidden in brain.

Comment: This is pretty much the answer, I was thinking "Words" plural because I say found once.  But the cord I was thinking vocal cord shine that's where words exit.  Good Job though!

Answer (score 1):

> Password

I can be weighed, but have no mass

> If contains numbers, uppercase and lowercase characters and so

And I can be found once in a sword

> Pas**sword**

I can be thoughtful or thoughtless

> thoughtless as 12345, thoughtful as S0m3P455w0rd

And I can exit through a cord

> cord as cable

Title: I'm good at hiding!

> as ****** or as hash, or when u hide your own password somewhere safe.

Comment: May I suggest: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/weigh-your-words

Comment: @HughMeyers yea, I was searching for that, but then don't know how Last line and Title fits :/

Comment: I was thinking vocal cords for the last line. Not sure about the title. Hiding in plain sight?

Comment: @HughMeyers Well then i guess post answer with that, since i never heard of vocal cord / weigh your words

Answer (score 1):

My guess is:

> **Truth**

I can be weighed, but have no mass

> They say that sometimes the truth can be *heavy*.  It all depends on what the truth is and who is saying it.

And I can be found once in a sword

> King Arthur and the Excalibur! "The act could not be performed except by the true king..." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excalibur#Excalibur_and_the_Sword_in_the_Stone

I can be thoughtful or thoughtless

> You may need to stop and think before revealing the truth in a given situation.

And I can exit through a cord

> As @HughMeyers mentioned, my thought went for the truth being heard via vocal cord.

Title: I'm good at hiding!

> The truth can hide, try and find it!

Answer (score 0):

I can be weighed, but have no mass

> Anger weighs you down

And I can be found once in a sword

> Once a person uses the Sword we know that he/she has anger

I can be thoughtful or thoughtless

> Anger can arise consciously or unconsciously

And I can exit through a cord

> Anger can be released through tongue by speaking bad things

What am I?

> Anger

Comment: Decently fits the lines, but this was not the answer.